# React-Native unable to run previous version 0.69 but current version runs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, react-native

Please I have configured android studio current version(hedgehog), jdk21 and node 21.5.0 to run react-native per what the documentation advised. When I create a project with version 0.73, I am able to run the emulator successfully. But when I create a project with version 0.69 because I want to use javascript and run the emulator, it give an error
`(node:11056) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The` punycode `module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.` and subsequently `Task :app:dexBuilderDebug FAILED`.

I have gone online to resolve it but there is no clear solution for it.. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling with this I found out that JDK21 compiled class files are not compatible with gradle features implemented 0.69. I had to painfully downgrade to JDK17 and also upgraded my node to 20.11.0. I also installed another emulator with api level 30 and its configurations to make the emulator run smoothly with react-native. I think api level 33 should run the app but I am not willing to try it..